# Change the timestamp from UTC to given format in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a timestamp value i.e "2021-08-18T16:49:42.175-06:00". how can i convert this to "2021-08-18T16:49:42.175Z" format in pyspark.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Pyspark DataFrame function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html) `date_format` to reformat your timestamp string to [any other format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html).

Example:

```
df = df.withColumn("ts_column", date_format("ts_column", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

`date_format` expects a TimestampType column so you might need to cast it Timestamp first if it currently is StringType

Answer (score -1):

Set the timeZone to "UTC" and read-only upt0 23 chars.

Try below:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
spark.sql(""" select to_timestamp('2021-08-18T16:49:42.175-06:00') as ts,
                date_format(to_timestamp(substr('2021-08-18T16:49:42.175-06:00',1,23)),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ') as ts2    from range(1) """).show(false)

+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|ts                     |ts2                         |
+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|2021-08-18 22:49:42.175|2021-08-18 16:49:42.175+0000|
+-----------------------+----------------------------+
```

Note that +0000 is UTC

If you want to get "Z", then use X

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
spark.sql(""" 
with t1 ( select to_timestamp('2021-08-18T16:49:42.175-06:00') as ts, 
        to_timestamp(substr('2021-08-18T16:49:42.175-06:00',1,23)) as ts2    from range(1) )

select *, date_format(ts2,'YYYY-MM-d HH:MM:ss.SX') ts3 from t1 
        """).show(false)

+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
|ts                     |ts2                    |ts3                     |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
|2021-08-18 22:49:42.175|2021-08-18 16:49:42.175|2021-08-18 16:08:42.175Z|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```